How can I call the /servicePrincipals(appId='{appId}') endpoint using the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK?
I want to retrieve the service principal object given an application ID.
The .NET SDK provides the following endpoint for that:
GET /servicePrincipals(appId='{appId}')
However, I don't see how to call that endpoint, only the one with the service principal's object ID:
await graphClient.ServicePrincipals[applicationId].PatchAsync(new ServicePrincipal
{
   AccountEnabled = false
}, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

Any ideas?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp
Furthermore, would it be possible to disable the service principal in a single call, instead of two, given the application ID?

The SDK should have the method ServicePrincipalsWithAppId
var result = await graphClient.ServicePrincipalsWithAppId("{appId}").GetAsync();

The PATCH is also possible
await graphClient.ServicePrincipalsWithAppId(applicationId).PatchAsync(new ServicePrincipal
{
   AccountEnabled = false
}, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);


I have called the below API using Graph Exporer and it give me the serviceprincial object for a specific application id.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '870c4f2e-85b6-4d43-bdda-6ed9a579b725'


We can fetch the serviceprincipal object of the specific application id using OData filter query parameter in C# as below.
var result = await graphClient.ServicePrincipals.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "appId eq '870c4f2e-85b6-4d43-bdda-6ed9a579b725'";
    requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");
});

